# round in PHP shows scientific notation instead of full number

Tags: php, floating-point, integer, rounding

I'm trying to do an echo of a variable containing 1400000. 
so there is written: `echo round(1400000);`
this gives 1,4E+6 instead of the full number.
Anybody an idea on how to display it fully?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that round was the problem.
I changed it with `number_format()` and this does the job just fine.
Thanks Aron and Paul for the answers.

Answer (score 7):

Related to your question, I also came across [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#83577) on the PHP website.

> PHP switches from the standard decimal
>   notation to exponential notation for
>   certain "special" floats. You can see
>   a partial list of such "special"
>   values with this:

```
for( $tmp = 0, $i = 0; $i < 100; $i++ ) 
{
    $tmp += 100000;
    echo round($tmp),"\n"; 
}
```

> So, if you add two floats, end up with
>   a "special" value, e.g. 1.2E+6, then
>   put that value unmodified into an
>   update query to store the value in a
>   decimal column, say, you will likely
>   get a failed transaction, since the
>   database will see "1.2E+6" as varchar
>   data, not decimal. Likewise, you will
>   likely get an XSD validation error if
>   you put the value into xml.
>
> I have to be honest: this is one of
>   the strangest things I have seen in
>   any language in over 20 years of
>   coding, and it is a colossal pain to
>   work around.

It seems there has not been a "real" fix yet, but judging from the comments in the [bug report Paul Dixon referered to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491154/round-in-php-shows-power-in-stead-of-full-number/491174#491174) earlier, his solution seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly related to this [bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43053), so you could try

```
printf("%d", $myvar);
```